# Edges with weights networkx

Tags: python, networkx

In a network like the code below:

```
G = nx.Graph()   # or DiGraph, MultiGraph, MultiDiGraph, etc
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,1,3.0),(1,2,7.5)])
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spectral_layout(G), with_labels=True)
```

How do I make the thickness of the edges to be proportional to the weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`nx.draw_networkx.edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html), which takes the argument `width`, and accepts lists.

So, given `G`, you can access the edges and weights like so:

```
G.edges(data=True)
```

This returns:

```
EdgeDataView([(0, 1, {'weight': 3.0}), (1, 2, {'weight': 7.5})])
```

So, edge data is stored as a list of tuples, whose element 2 is a dictionary, with the key 'weight'. This allows you to access the individual weights, using a list comprehension:

```
edge_width = [a[2]['weight'] for a in G.edges(data=True)]

nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spectral_layout(G), with_labels=True) # draw nodes (and edges!)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=nx.spectral_layout(G), width=edge_width) # paint over edges with specified width.
```

[image]

For the nodes, I chose to use `nx.draw`, rather than `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`, because I couldn't find a straightforward way to include `with_labels`. Bear in mind that `nx.draw` already draws the edges with fixed width. For the application presented, this does not matter, but you could run into issues when using transparency. To avoid those, you could use `nx.draw` on a graph without edges, add the edges, and then use `nx.draw_networkx_edges`